# Clear form inputs and keep placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

I know that using this `jQuery` tool

```
$('.myDiv input').each(function () {
   $(this).val("");
});
```

clears my form but can anyone help me with some suggestions how to keep `placeholders` of the input?

Right now the placeholders appears only after I focus on at least one input.

Comment: What happens if you add `$('input').focus().blur();` to the end?

Comment: Reason why you are reinventing `form.reset()`?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/s8vPG/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **jQuery**

```
function Clear()
{      
     $('.myDiv input').each(function () {
   $(this).val("");
         x=1;
    });
        $('.myDiv input').first().focus();          
}
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/s8vPG/2/

Comment: what is the difference between http://jsfiddle.net/s8vPG/  and your fiddle? both seems to provide the same output.

Comment: i add focus option for the first input in div :)