# JavaScript: element.setAttribute(attribute,value) , element.attribute=value & element.[attribute]=value not changing attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, css, setattribute

My task is to remove Placeholder from input box when user clicks on it and make label visible.
If user doesn't fill anything in it again place back the placeholder and make label invisible.

I am able to hide it but can't reassign it.
I have tried element.setAttribute(attribute,value) , element.attribute=value & element.[attribute]=value type but isn't working.

I have kept default `visibility` of `<label>` `"hidden"`

I have created hide() and show() functions for the task both having 2 parameters viz.

1. id of input box
2. id of label

Code JavaScript:

```
var placehlder;


function hide(input_id,lbl){
            var e1=document.getElementById(input_id);
            placehlder=e1.getAttribute('placeholder');
            /*document.write(placehlder);*/
            e1.placeholder="";
            var e2=document.getElementById(lbl);
            e2.style.visibility="visible";
        }
function show(input_id,lbl){
            var e1=window.document.getElementById(input_id).value;
            var e2=document.getElementById(lbl);
            /*document.write(placehlder);*/
            if (e1.length ==0) 
            {
                e2.style.visibility="hidden";
                e1.placeholder=placehlder;
                /*e1.setAttribute('placeholder',placehlder);*/
                /*e1['placeholder']=placehlder;*/
            }
     }
```

Code HTML:

```
<form>
        <label id="first" >First Name</label><br/>
        <input id="box" type="text" placeholder="First Name" onclick="hide(id,'first')" onfocusout="show(id,'first')"/>

</form>
```

Full Code: HTML + CSS + JAVASCRIPT:

```js
        var placehlder;
        function hide(input_id,lbl){
            var e1=document.getElementById(input_id);
            placehlder=e1.getAttribute('placeholder');
            /*document.write(placehlder);*/
            e1.placeholder="";
            var e2=document.getElementById(lbl);
            e2.style.visibility="visible";
        }
        function show(input_id,lbl){
            var e1=window.document.getElementById(input_id).value;
            var e2=document.getElementById(lbl);
            /*document.write(placehlder);*/
            if (e1.length ==0) 
            {
                e2.style.visibility="hidden";
                e1.placeholder=placehlder;
                /*e1.setAttribute('placeholder',placehlder);*/
                /*e1['placeholder']=placehlder;*/
            }
        }
```

```css
        #first{

            visibility: hidden;
        }
        #box{

        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>
        Functions
    </title>

    

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label id="first" >First Name</label><br/>
        <input id="box" type="text" placeholder="First Name" onclick="hide(id,'first')" onfocusout="show(id,'first')"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 1:
I have got the solution to my problem using CSS in answer by @Darlesson .
But if possible please tell whats wrong in my Code.
EDIT 2:
As pointed by @lenilsondc my code didn't worked because of `var e1` didn't had element but the `value attribute` of element.

`var e1=window.document.getElementById(input_id).value;`

replaced to

`var e1=window.document.getElementById(input_id);`

did worked with `e1.placeholder=placehlder;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear form inputs and keep placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442349/clear-form-inputs-and-keep-placeholder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use CSS for the placeholder portion instead:

```
:focus::placeholder{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```css
:focus::placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Visible">
```

Comment: But how to re-assign the placeholder value?

Comment: In this case you wouldn't. It hides the placeholder text using opacity on focus and then shows it on blur. Is that the behaviour you are expecting? Run the snippet to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without any JS, and only HTML/CSS something like;

```css
.group {
  display: flex;
}

.group label {
  display: none;
  order: 1;
}

.group input {
  order: 2;
  display: block;
}
.group input:focus ~ label {
  display: block;
}

/* 
   note: browser compatibility is only ~82% 
   https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder
*/
.group input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <input type="text" id="id1" placeholder="Description">
  <label for="id1">Description</label>
</div>
```

Comment: i only added the code for chrome, so if you do not use chrome, your are correct.

Comment: I use mozilla firefox.

Comment: i updated the code, but still not 100% browser support

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do this using css ([using @Darlesson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51639331/4488121)) for compatibility reasons, you can do this as the following snippet using javascript.

The trick is to store the old placeholder so that when you need to restore you have it available. In this case I used a new attribute `data-placeholder` where I store de current value and clean the real `placeholder` attribute. Finally, when the element lose focus, you can get the attribute `data-placeholder` and reset the real `placeholder` value with it.

```js
var myInputLabel = document.getElementById('myInputLabel');
var myInput      = document.getElementById('myInput');

// when element gets focused
myInput.addEventListener('focus', function (e) {

  // save current placeholder
  myInput.setAttribute('data-placeholder', myInput.getAttribute('placeholder'));
 
  // clear current placeholder 
  myInput.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
  
  // show label
  myInputLabel.style.display = 'inline';
});

// when element gets blured
myInput.addEventListener('blur', function (e) {

  // restore the placeholder stored on data-placeholder
  myInput.setAttribute('placeholder', myInput.getAttribute('data-placeholder'));
  
  // hide label
  myInputLabel.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label id="myInputLabel" style="display: none;">Name</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Name">
</form>
```

Comment: As you can see in my code I too have used variable "placehlder" to store placeholder value. But what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Because of this `var e1=window.document.getElementById(input_id).value`. e1 is the value of the element, then when you try to set `e1.placeholder` you ar not referencing the element but its value; therefore, it never gets the placeholder set.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var input = document.getElementById("box");
 var label = document.getElementById("first");

 // When the user clicks on the input element
 input.addEventListener("focus", function() {

  // Make label visible
  first.style.visibility = "visible";

  // Remvoe placeholder
  input.placeholder = "";
 });

 // When the user clicks away
 input.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
 
  // Check if he did not typed anything
  if (input.value === "") {
   // Restore placeholder value and hide label
   input.placeholder = "First Name";
   first.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

 });
```

```css
       #first{

            visibility: hidden;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>
        Functions
    </title>

    <style>
        #first{

            visibility: hidden;
        }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label id="first" >First Name</label><br/>
        <input id="box" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />

    </form>
    
    </body>
</html>
```